# Type Families and Sum Type Classes

Tags: haskell, typeclass, type-families

Having the following data types and type classes:

```
data T1 a

data T2 a

data T3 a

class TC1 a where
   m1 :: T1 a

class TC2 a where
   m2 :: T2 a

class TC3 a where
   m3 :: T3 a
```

I'd like to write a function like this one:

```
dummy :: (TC1 a | TC2 a | TC3 a) => a
```

Meaning that 'a' should have **either** `TC1` **or** `TC2`  **or** `TC3` as type class constraint. For example, these functions should type check:

```
dummyInt :: T2 Int
dummyInt = dummy

dummyChar :: T1 Char
dummyChar = dummy
```

My first thought was to create a dummy type class with no methods:

```
class TC a

instance TC (T1 a)

instance TC (T2 a)

instance TC (T3 a)
```

Now, the examples above type check correctly using this signature:

```
dummy :: TC a => a
```

But, first of all, am I abusing type classes here? What are the pitfalls of this approach?

Otherwise, if this is alright, it could get messy with more type variables and type classes. Is there a less clunky way to do this?

I tried with a type families along these lines:

```
data family TF a
data instance TF a = T1 a | T2 a | T3 a

class Dummy a where
    dummy :: TF a

instance Dummy Int where
    dummy = undefined

...
```

Even if I had access to changing the type constructors, which I don't, I think I'd still need to wrap them with new ones for the data family which in the end it doesn't end up simplifying the code that much.

Secondly, while it'd be nice to unify `m1`, `m2` and `m3` into a single method in a single type class and get rid of the `TC1`, `TC2` and `TC3` type classes, I'd then have to use explicit data constructors when defining new instances. Ideally, I wish I could use synonym families like this:

```
type instance TF a = T1 | T2 | T3
```

Comment: What use do you have for this?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, the open world assumption means that negating a constraint is impossible

Comment: Maybe you can do this with constraint kinds, but I’m not completely sure.

Comment: @Rhymoid I have to deal with a crazy monad transformer stack. My original intention was to shorten the type signatures with a type class *alias* that could be used to represent any of the other type classes.

Comment: @rightfold, you are right! I didn't articulate the question properly but it turns out I was actually looking for constraint kinds as they are being used in [`ConstraintKinds`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/ConstraintKinds).

Comment: @DannyNavarro since you solved it, care to post that as an answer to your question?

Comment: @sclv I tried to find where I used `ConstrainKinds` but couldn't find it. I'm totally out of context these days but I'll try to answer as soon as I find the time to dig deeper. My bad for not posting the answer back then!